# Getting config variables outside of the application context

Tags: python, configuration, flask, config

I've extracted several of my sqlalchemy models to a separate and installable package (../lib/site-packages), to use across several applications. So I only need to:

```
from models_package import MyModel
```

from any application needing access to these models.

Everything is ok so far, except I cannot find a satisfactory way of getting several application dependent config variables used by some of the models, which may vary from application to application. So some model need to be aware of some variables, where previously I've used the application they were in.

Neither

```
current_app.config['XYZ']
```

or

```
config = LocalProxy(lambda: current_app.config['XYZ'])
```

have worked (`outside of application context` errors) so I'm stuck right now. Maybe this is poor programming and/or design on my behalf, so how do clear this up? There must be some way, but I haven't reasoned myself toward it yet.

SOLUTION:

Avoiding setting items that would occur on module load (like a constant containing an api key), both of the above *should* work, and they do. Anything not using those in the context of model-in-the-application use will of course error, methods returning the values you need should be good.

Comment: did you try just importing application object (not by `current_app` proxy) from your `models_package`?

Comment: models_package is separate and has no app object, models from there get imported into an application.

Comment: sometimes circular-imports solve a problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a configuration pattern utilising classes and inheritance [as described here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/config/#configuration-best-practices), you could simply import your config classes with their respective properties and access them anywhere you want:

```
class Config(object):
    IMPORT = 'ME'
    DEBUG = False
    TESTING = False
    DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite:///:memory:'

class ProductionConfig(Config):
    DATABASE_URI = 'mysql://user@localhost/foo'

class DevelopmentConfig(Config):
    DEBUG = True

class TestingConfig(Config):
    TESTING = True
```

Now, in your `foo.py`:

```
from config import Config

print(Config.IMPORT) # prints 'ME'
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that you still need to get the current environment from app so you will know which of the config options to use.

Answer (score 0):

well, since `current_app` can be a proxy of your flask program when the blueprint is registered, and that is done at run-time, you can't use it in your `models_package` modules.
(app tries to import `models_package`, and `models_package` requires app's configs to initalize things- thus import fails)

one option would be doing circular imports :

assuming everything is in 'App' module:

**__init__.py**

```
import flask

application = flask.Flask(__name__)
application.config = #load configs

import models_package
```

**models_package.py**

```
from App import application
config = application.config
```

or create your own `config` object, but that somehow doubles complexity:

**models_package.py**

```
import flask

config = flask.config.Config(defaults=flask.Flask.default_config)

#pick one of those and apply the same config initialization as you do in 
#your __init__.py
config.from_pyfile(..) #or
config.from_object(..) #or
config.from_envvar(..)
```

Comment: One issue, is that aside from a few config variables, the models have no knowledge of the application. Having to import an app into the models would tie them together unduly where the whole point of packaging them was to have them separate from their application, and the solution is too successful perhaps.